# Learning web sockets and ran into a problem following a guide

Tags: c#, websocket

I am looking at implementing a web socket server - more of a learning experience than anything else - Want to get an idea of how it works from the ground up.

I am looking at this example :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

But I get an exception on this `ulong msglen = bytes[1] & 0b01111111;` that "Cannot convert initializer type from int to ulong"

There is also an issue here `decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);` as offset is an int and i is ulong

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to cast : ulong msglen = (ulong)(bytes[1] & 0b01111111);

Comment: I thought that might be it, just wasn't sure if I'd cause a problem :)

Comment: Not sure why you need to cast a byte to a ulong.

Comment: Me either - following a tutorial :)